# Sorting algorithm with Java streams

Tags: algorithm, sorting, java-stream

There is a list of String currency ISO codes in random order: CHF, USD, AUD, EUR, 0995, AED... etc.

Is there an algorithm to sort it in the following order: first should go only main currencies (USD, CHF, EUR) - in exactly this order, then alphabetically all other currencies, then all numeric currency codes?

As of now i do it in 3 steps by simply creating 3 separate lists, sorting them accordingly and then making list.addAll. Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a custom comparator would be the ideal way to tackle this scenario.

```java
public class CurrencyComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> currencyList = Arrays.asList("CHF", "USD", "AUD", "EUR", "0995", "AED");
        currencyList.sort(new CurrencyComparator());
        currencyList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private int getTypeOrder(String cur) {
        switch (cur) {
            case "USD":
                return 0;
            case "CHF":
                return 1;
            case "EUR":
                return 2;
            default:
                return cur.matches("[A-Za-z]*") ? 3 : 4;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String cur1, String cur2) {
        int typeOrder1 = getTypeOrder(cur1);
        int typeOrder2 = getTypeOrder(cur2);
        if (typeOrder1 != typeOrder2) {
            return Integer.compare(typeOrder1, typeOrder2);
        }
        return cur1.compareTo(cur2);
    }
}
```

It will produce the below output

```
USD
CHF
EUR
AED
AUD
0995
```